# Code to do a direct DNS lookup

Tags: dns, network-protocols

I'm thinking of running an experiment to track DNS values in different ways (like how often they change and whatnot). To do this I will need to be able to make a DNS request directly to a server so that 1) I known what server it came from, 2) I can request responses from several servers and 3) I can avoid the local OS run cache.

*Does anyone know of a library (c#, D, C, C++ in that order of preference) that will let me directly query a DNS server?* Failing that, does anyone know of a easy to understand description of the DNS protocol that I could implement such a system from?

Comment: Is wrapping a tool like host(1) is out of the question?

Comment: Also, remember to be nice to DNS servers that aren't yours.

Comment: I figure a few hundred request a day wouldn't even be noticed. I might run that many from my browser alone

Comment: don't known about host(1) as I can't tell how it interacts with the OS DNS cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have experience only with C, so here is my list:

- libresolv is the old, traditional and standard way. It is available on every Unix (type `man 3 resolver`) and includes routines like 
  `res_query` which does more or less what you want. To query a specific name server, you typically update the global variable `_res.nsaddr_list` (do note that, apparently, it [does not work with IPv6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388930/using-the-name-resolver-of-resolv-h-with-ipv6)).
- [ldns](http://www.nlnetlabs.nl/projects/ldns/) is the modern and shiny solution. You have [good documentation online](http://www.nlnetlabs.nl/projects/ldns/doc/tutorial1_mx.html).
- a very common library, but apparently unmaintained, is [adns](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~ian/adns/).

Comment: Then, do not forget to publish it to provide nice examples for the newcomers :-)

Answer (score 3):

For C, I'd go with http://cr.yp.to/djbdns/blurb/library.html (the low-level parts if you need total control, i.e. `dns_transmit*` and friends) -- for C#, maybe http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ivxivx/DNSClient12122005234612PM/DNSClient.aspx (can't test that one right now, whence the "maybe"!).

Comment: I can't download the c# one <grrr/> but the C one looks good so far.

Comment: The C one is Unix only (I can live with that but it's not my first choice)

Comment: The djb library seems unable to do IPv6 lookups or, simply, to do lookups for arbitrary resource recode types such as NAPTR or SRV.

Answer (score 3):

The DNS specification is spread over **many** [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc.html) (see a [nice graph](http://blog.nominet.org.uk/tech/2010/05/24/436/)) and I would strongly advise **not** to implement a stub resolver from scratch. There are many opportunities to get it wrong. The DNS evolved a lot in the last years. If you are brave and crazy, here are the most important RFC:

- RFC 1034, concepts
- RFC 1035, format
- RFC 2181, update to the specification, to fix many errors or ambiguities
- RFC 2671, EDNS (mandatory today)
- RFC 3597, handling the unknown resource record types
- and many others...

Answer (score 0):

libdns (I think it's part of bind). There's a cygwin port which may be useful for windows environments.

http://rpm2html.osmirror.nl/libdns.so.21.html

Comment: In the Windows world there is this nice function named DNSQuery()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682016%28VS.85%29.aspx